# Is it possible to connect an existing JCR repository to Liferay?

Tags: java, repository, liferay, jcr, liferay-6

I'm wondering if I can setup liferay to use my existing JackRabbit repository via `com.liferay.documentlibrary.util.JCRHook`

If I set all these properties to match my repository, would it work ?

```
jcr.workspace.name=liferay
jcr.node.documentlibrary=documentlibrary

jcr.jackrabbit.repository.root=${liferay.home}/data/jackrabbit
jcr.jackrabbit.config.file.path=${jcr.jackrabbit.repository.root}/repository.xml
jcr.jackrabbit.repository.home=${jcr.jackrabbit.repository.root}/home
jcr.jackrabbit.credentials.username=none
jcr.jackrabbit.credentials.password=none
```

The repository is mostly about `nt:file - nt:content with nt:resources`  that has "jcr" and mixin properties. I'm not interested in those, I just need the files in repository to be accessible via Liferay's document library.

I'd like to avoid using CMIS integration and do it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for now, you can only connect an existing repository via CMIS. So that your repository has to be running on a server with cmis server support, into which your repo is bound to.

There is a proposition going on, you can vote up [here](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/8022792).